# What are best practices for authorizing and sharing API resources across accounts?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, rest, api-design

I have a simple REST API built in Node.js, Express and MongoDB—technologies really don't matter though since I'm looking more at design than anything. A typical route looks something like this:

```js
router.get('/doc/:id', async function(req, res, next) {

  const loggedInUserId = req.session.user.id;

  const doc = await db.docs.findOne({_id:req.params.id, user:loggedInUserId});

  if (!doc) {
    return next( new Error('not found') )
  }

  return res.json(doc);

});
```

I know the user is the owner of the document since I use the logged in user's id in the document query. However, if it's a shared document this approach won't works. I need to think of a better way to authorize a "team".

My initial thought on this is to allow the owner of a "document" to share it with another user by adding them to a `teams` collection. In this case the route might look something like this:

```js
router.get('/doc/:id', async function(req, res, next) {

  const loggedInUserId = req.session.user.id;

  // here I check the teams collection to see if the logged
  // in user has been given access the document.
  const hasAccess = await db.teams.exists({
    doc:res.params.id,
    users:loggedInUserId
  });

  if (!hasAccess) {
    return next( new Error('forbidden') )
  }

  const doc = await db.docs.findOne({ _id:req.params.id });

  if (!doc) {
    return next( new Error('not found') )
  }

  return res.json(doc);

});
```

This approach may work for simple scenarios but I'm worried it could get messy when adding additional features like read/write/delete access, pagination, concurrency control, etc. Not to mention this approach may considerably slow down my API since most users will be accessing their own resources and will not be part of a team.

I'm still in the germination phase for this and I'd like to have a solid plan in place before I move forward. Does this seem like a good path or am I missing something? Is there a "best practice" for authorizing resources across accounts?

Thanks

Comment: I presume you don't mean `return doc`.  Do you mean `res.json(doc)` or something that sends a response to the request?

Comment: @jfriend00, yes of course, I'll update to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Decided to give this problem a go. Have a look at my approach, hope it helps. I think directly using query is a much faster approach, besides, it's only a single query.

---

### Pseudo models

```
users
- id
- name

teams
- id
- name
- owner_id > user_teams.id

user_teams
- id
- teams_id
- users_id > users.id

permissions
- id
- name

user_permissions
- users_id > users.id
- permissions_id > permissions.id

document_permissions
- documents_id > documents.id
- permissions_id > permissions.id

documents
- id
- file_url
- owner_id > users.id
- teams_id > teams.id nullable
```

### Make Believe Queries

User's documents

```sql
SELECT file_url FROM documents WHERE owner_id = <current_user_id>
```

`Shared With Me` documents

```sql
SELECT
    doc.file_url,
    p.name as access_type,
    owner.name AS owner
FROM documents doc

LEFT JOIN users owner ON doc.owner_id = owner.id
LEFT JOIN permissions p ON dp.permissions_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN document_permissions dp ON dp.documents_id = doc.id
LEFT JOIN teams t ON doc.teams_id = t.id

WHERE t.users_id = <current_user_id>

-- If the document's permission is not available for the user means it's not assigned
AND dp.permissions_id IN (
    SELECT permissions_id FROM user_permissions up
    WHERE up.users_id = <current_user_id>
)
```

The query above can then be translated (hopefully) into whatever ORM you're using to be used in the code.

Comment: Hmm...my perspective is on relational database, which is what Mongodb is not. Sorry about that. I guess you could store the permissions and teams metadata in the `document` model and just do the query there, but I suppose that's not what Mongodb is designed for.

Comment: Ya, this is essential what I'm doing. since I can put *all* the permissions in a single collection I don't need multiple tables and joins. I can simple query the `teams` collection (table) and ensure the logged in user is a part of it.

Comment: Yeah — but you'll have a hard time maintaining the document's permission relationships & integrity, which is not Mongodb's forte.